# How to filter objects in mongoengine using 'LIKE' statement?

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have following json structure in my mongodb.

```
{

    "country": "spain",
    "language": "spanish",
    "words": [
        {
            "word": "hello1",
             ....
         },
         {
            "word": "hello2",
             ....
         },
          {
            "word": "test",
             ....
         },
       ]
}
```

I am trying to get all the dictionaries inside 'words' list which have particular substring matched.

For example, If I have a substring 'hel', then how should I query my document using mongoengine that gives two dictionary with word : 'hello1' and 'hello2'

The following query works only for matched word not with the substring.

```
 data = Data.objects.filter(words__match={"word":"hel"})
    // data is empty in this case([])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$elemMatch` (`match` in mongoengine)  will return the first element that matches the criteria, from the array.

You need to use aggregation to return all matching elements from your array:

```
pipeline = [
    { "$unwind": "$words" },
    { "$match": {"words.word": {"$regex": "hel"} } },
    { "$project": {"word":"$words.word", "_id":0} },
]

Article.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)
```

result:

```
{u'word': u'hello1'}
{u'word': u'hello2'}
```

Note, using this project stage you need to know all the fields in advance so you can specify them in the projection to return them.

You can also use this project for a different output, to return all fields but wrapped in a 'words dict':

```
pipeline = [
    { "$unwind": "$words" },
    { "$match": {"words.word": {"$regex": "hel"} } },
    { "$project": {"words":1, "_id":0} },
]
```

result:

```
{u'words': {u'otherfield': 1.0, u'word': u'hello1'}}
{u'words': {u'otherfield': 1.0, u'word': u'hello2'}}
```